# Any way to hide/fold swagger annotations in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, swagger

My controller has some set of swagger annotations with large descriptions. which makes the file messy and hard to track the code.

Example code block
[Swagger annotations used in the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEDGG.jpg)

Is there any way to hide or fold swagger or any other annotations in eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can externalize your strings into a Constants or properties or yaml to get a clean code

```
@ApiParam(value = "${swagger.sample.request.ApiParam.value}") 
@RequestBody(required = true) 
List request,

@ApiParam(value = DocumentationConstants.SAMPLE, required = true) 
@RequestHeader(value = "sample", required = true) 
String example,
```

Ref:[Externalization](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

Comment: springfox can be used to externalise descriptions of api annotations to property file using maven.